# Firebird and Hibernate - How do you specify a DB role?

Tags: java, hibernate, firebird, jaybird, firebird-3.0

I'm working in a new project to convert our Delphi + Firebird system to Java 8 / JavaFX / JPA (Hibernate) and Firebird. We are using the latest version of Jaybird and connecting to Firebird 1.5, Firebird 3.0 and InterBase XE3 databases. I have not found any documentation on connecting to the DB specifying a DB role. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Jaybird does not support InterBase XE3, and if it works that is by accident.

Answer (score 0):

To specify the user role, you need to specify the `roleName` property in the connection string. See also [Extended connection properties](https://firebirdsql.github.io/jaybird-manual/jaybird_manual.html#connectionproperties) in *Jaybird JDBC Driver Java Programmer's Manual*.

Example of a connection string:

```
jdbc:firebirdsql://localhost/database?charSet=UTF-8&roleName=myrole
```

Comment: I was able to connect with: <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:firebirdsql:cbcs2k8:/cw2db/test347.GDB?roleName=CWUSR;</property> .  But if I put in the charSet=UTF-8 it  threw errors.  Thanks for you help Mark.

Comment: @DavidCulbertson What was the error? Which version of Jaybird & Firebird?

Comment: @DavidCulbertson Also note that the config file you use is XML, so `&` needs to be written as `&amp;` (or you can use `;`)

Comment: "GDB" is obsolete extension and is not recommended starting with WinXP